# Multiple configurable products as a bundle

Tags: catalog, bundled-product

We have many products that we sell in different sizes. We have set up 1 configurable product and linked all the simple product sizes.

But now we wish to set-up a bundled product that consists of a pack of 3 configurable products (like red, green and blue shirt). And when the users for the bundle it should show the same "select size" option as it does with configurable products.

Can this be done?

Comment: Anyone ideas. This must be possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible **out-of-the box** with Magento.

There are a few community extensions on Magento Connect - I have not used them personally. They used to be more prevalent - even Classy Llama had one. There was also one called Package Builder that I cannot find anymore.

So this might be your best bet:

**Configurable Bundle by Wizkunde**

https://www.wizkunde.nl/magento-2-configurable-bundle.html

**Configurable products by Brim**

http://www.brimllc.com/2010/12/magento-grouped-products-containing-associated-configurable-products/

If you want to **forgo the idea of using bundles**, Grouped Products offer the ability to add configurables to the group.

Comment: I've used the Brim extension, it worked perfectly out of the box.

Comment: Judging by score at MagentoConnect the extension by Wizkunde had hardly be called "best bet". Also it is a commercial one and we really do not encourage people to promote commercial extensions at StackExchange.

Comment: Tim - the score at MC is from *one* review and it seems the reviewer was not technically able to implement it; I would hardly call that a fair judgment of the product. I've never used it, and I can't endorse it; just trying to help point in the right direction. As far as promotion - I think we landed in the Meta discussion that we are not discouraging paid extensions in these types of answers. I do not work for or have ever used the Wizkunde extension, merely pointing out an option. Any suggestion of my intentions otherwise are off base and unwelcomed.

Comment: @SanderMangel did you use it to create the configurable bundles? And how does it work for instance with feed extensions and api s shooting in remote orders? (The type of product not being native)

Comment: @snh_nl jup. and regarding being non-native; in the end it's still a simple or configurable product but wrapped. Can't really guarantee it will work but it shouldn't require too much tweaking I'd say

Comment: Thx. In essence the only thing that needs to be done (to solve the question) is to create a stock multiplier. So if a pack consists of 3 sub products. Ordering 1 should result in qty = 3 for stock deduction. And even on invoice. So adding a multiplier observer should solve it everywhere and make it compatible with all other processes. Where would one add such a multiplier?

Comment: Please update your answer -The URLs are broke or lead to spam.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to bring your attention to th new Magento 2 extension which was shared with the community by eWave and provides exactly requested features to the merchants. You are able to create/manage bundles which consist of configurable products through the admin panel or default API using "Configurable Products In Bundles" extension.

Please take a moment to review details on the extension page https://marketplace.magento.com/ewave-extendedbundleproduct.html

and try a demo:

Storefront: https://extendedbundle.ewavedemo.com/configurable-products-in-bundle.html

Back-office: https://extendedbundle.ewavedemo.com/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/2058/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We did this for a customer with a custom module written for this particular case.

Here is an example https://www.apolloecigs.com/en/3-salt-nic-e-liquids-1-free-pod-system

The plugin accounts for the inventory management on both front-end (by hiding out of stock options) and back-end by linking the front-end options to simple products.

Comment: Thanks. But how does this work with market places where one exports real backend products with their own sku and barcode thanks 